# iphone map view in app

Tags: view, dictionary, crash, memory-leaks

I have a map view in my app in simulator works fine but when i test it on my ipod touch -2g 8gb sometimes it crashes could it be because my ipod is a bit old and don't have that much memory? in simulator everything works fine! and the leaks instrument shows no leaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be the case. The simulator has no memory limits that are relevant. Your old iPod does (though the 8GB is not the relevant number).

If you run the iPod connected to your computer and launch it from Xcode, does the crash happen, and does it have no stack trace? Then it's most likely memory.

Comment: yes as i said it ipod touch -2G! when i first open my app i have 44MB Free memory and after maps and some other arrays load ends less than 10MB

Comment: Then it's most likely memory. Are you getting a memory warning? You can put a debug breakpoint in the memory warning call on your app delegate.

Comment: no i dont get memory warning it just crashes! Also it's a jailbroken device! do you think that it might affect too?